# EC2 instance connection refused: unprotected private key file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I accidentally set 0775 permission for "/" while trying to fix permission problem for HADOOP and when I restarted my instance it says connection refused.
When I check system log (from instance settings) this message are among the last messages in the log.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0775 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

According to this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#d0e105559 and many other solution on the internet, I should run some command like

```
chmod 0400 .ssh/my_private_key.pem
```

but the problem is I can't access the instance, so I can't run that command from that instance.

Anyone has any idea about this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: What is the output of `ssh -v ......` command when you try to access the instance?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/523127/aws-ec2-how-can-i-recover-files-now-that-im-no-longer-able-to-ssh-into-my-ser see the answers there.

Comment: @helloV I'm using putty so I didn't get any response except the popup saying connection resufed

Comment: @MarkB I have the system setup, is there a way to fix this instance. Also, I don't have any extra volume attached to that instance, and I can't detach the root volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one way to do this.

1. Stop the instance having bad permission.
2. Detach the Root Volume (check the volume id).
3. Launch a new Instance and attach the volume that you took out in Step 2.
4. Mount the volume on the new Instance at any mount point /temp-perm.
5. Save the changes and again detach the volume that you attach in Step 4.
6. Re-attach the volume to your old Instance that you stopped in Step 1.